# Problem with PHP function -- Adding links to index via config file (multiple links)

Tags: php

So I am currently working on a small project, which is going to have a config file where I can edit/add more links etc.

So what I am trying to do is the following. 
When I add a new `$link = addLink` inside *`config.php`* it will automatically add the link to the home page. But as of now, it doesn't add the links to the home page. When I echo out `$url['link']`, but if I do `$link['link']` it `echo`'s out the first link and not both. I have tried this with a while loop, `foreach` and`for`.

i am not sure if this is the best way to do this.

Here is some of my code: 
**config.php**

```
$link      = addLink("https://forums.website.com;Forums"); 
$link      = addLink("https://donate.website.com;Donate");
```

my function: 
**function.php**

```
function addLink($link){
    $arrLink         = explode(";", $link);
    $url['link']     = $arrLink[0];
    $url['name']     = $arrLink[1];
    $url['navlink']  = "<li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='".$url['link'] ."'>".$url['name'] ."<a></li>";
    return $url;
}
```

All advisees on how I can do this is welcome! I will also keep this updated if I find and solution!

Comment: you got only one element , that is true ?

Comment: Every time you write `$link      = addLink...` you overwrite the $link variable with a new value. Is $link supposed to be an array containing all your link objects? It's unclear. Maybe you should be doing `$link[]      = addLink...` each time. But I'm not sure because the code you've shown is completely out of context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is *overwriting* the `$link` variable --  What you're going to want to do is `push` the `return` into an `array`

Something LIKE

```
$link = array();

array_push($link, addLink("https://forums.website.com;Forums"));
array_push($link, addLink("https://donate.website.com;Donate"));

print_r($link);
```

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do this, maybe there are some other ways.

1. use variable reference to keep the url list, this is not OOP style.

```php
function addLink($link, &$urls){
    $arrLink         = explode(";", $link);
    $url['link']     = $arrLink[0];
    $url['name']     = $arrLink[1];
    $url['navlink']  = "<li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='".$url['link'] ."'>".$url['name'] ."<a></li>";
    if (!$urls) {
        $urls = [];
    }
    $urls[] = $url;
    return $url;
}
$urls = [];
$link      = addLink("https://forums.website.com;Forums", $urls); 
$link      = addLink("https://donate.website.com;Donate", $urls);
```

2. Use OOP style.

```php
class Nav {
    protected static $urls = [];
    public static function add($link, $name="") {
        $url = [];

        $url['link']     = $link;
        $url['name']     = $name;
        $url['navlink']  = "<li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='".$url['link'] ."'>".$url['name'] ."<a></li>";
        self::$urls[] = $url;
        return $url;
    }

    public static function getUrls() {
        return self::$urls;
    }
}
Nav::add("https://forums.website.com", "Forums");
Nav::add("https://donate.website.com", "Donate");

$urls = Nav::getUrls();
```

I think the second way is better.

Comment: The second example is nice. In the first example you repeat the same error as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try this :

```
function addLink($link){
    $arrLink         = explode(";", $link);
    $url[]['link']     = $arrLink[0];
    $url[]['name']     = $arrLink[1];
    $url[]['navlink']  = "<li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='".$arrLink[0] ."'>".$arrLink[1] ."<a></li>";
    return $url;
}
```

The code you have been tried will only replace the existed element , that why you have to add [] before .